# SMS content provider cursor empty

Tags: android, cursor, sms

This is code for get SMS log in a period of selected date but it returns empty cursor:

```
        long lFrom = login.getTime();
        long lTo= logout.getTime();

        String[] whereValue = {String.valueOf(lFrom),String.valueOf(lTo)};
 Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(allMessages, new String[]{"date", "type", "address"},
            Telephony.Sms.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", whereValue, null);
```